# In symfony request how do I get the uri path without the query params?

Tags: php, symfony, path, request

```
$request = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request()
$request->getRequestUri();
```

Seems to return the path and the query params. How to I get just the path?

Comment: Have a look at this. [Getting full information about the request with onKernelController event listener](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/dpv0/getting-full-information-about-the-request-with-on-kernel-controller-event-listener)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
strtok($request->getRequestUri(), '?');
```

...or...

```
$request->getBaseUrl() . $request->getPathInfo();
```

Answer (score 15):

`$request->getPathInfo()` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use just PHP for that matter :

```
$urlWithoutQueryString = strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?');
```

Comment: Sorry, the question specified Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me in Laravel 5.7. I ended up using the following to get the full request URI without the query string:

```
$uri = strtok($request->getUri(), '?');
```

This will return `https://example.com/request/uri` for a request made to `https://example.com/request/uri?param=1`.